# How to calculate the tax percentage in Django Query set?

Tags: django, django-models

**Hello I m trying to calculate the invoice items total tax and final total amount**
**no, invoice_code, tax_amount, net_amount**
**Here model**

```
 class PriceMaster(models.Model):
    status_type = (
        ('a','Active'),
        ('d','Deactive')
    )
    items = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gst = models.ForeignKey(Gst, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_type, default = 'a')
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.items)

    @property
    def cgst_unround(self):
        if not hasattr(self,'_cgst'):
            self._cgst = self.price * self.gst.gst / 100
        return round(self._cgst,2)

    @property
    def per_gst(self):
        self.per = self.gst.gst / 2
        return self.per

    @property
    def cgst(self):
        return round((self.cgst_unround / 2),2)
    
    @property
    def NetAmount(self):
        self.net_amount = self.price + self.cgst_unround
        return round(self.net_amount,2)
    
    
    
class Invoice(models.Model):
    status_type = (
        ('a','Active'),
        ('d','Deactive')
    )
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_type, default = 'a', blank=True)
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.invoice_no)

def InvoiceNoGenarat(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        quote_id = instance
        quote_obj = Invoice.objects.get(id = int(quote_id.id))
        invoice_no = Invoice.objects.all().count()
        quote_query = Invoice.objects.filter(id = quote_id.id).update(invoice_no = str(invoice_no))

post_save.connect(InvoiceNoGenarat, sender = Invoice)

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    items_price = models.ForeignKey(PriceMaster,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoices = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

[image]

**Here my view.py I don't know how to make query**

```
def InvoicePage(request):
    user_id =request.user
    heading_name = "invoice"
    rights, main_heading, page_menu, form_btn_data = RightLoader(user_id, heading_name)
    search, add, update, view, Print, Password = BtnLoader(form_btn_data)
    #test = InvoiceItem.objects.annotate(total = F('items_price__price')*('quantity'))  
    
    try:
        auth_check = rights.pages.get(page_url = "invoice")
        if request.method == "POST":
            status = request.POST.get('status')
            if status != 'al':
                data = Invoice.objects.filter(status = status)
            else:
                data = Invoice.objects.all()
        else:
            data = ""
        context = {
            'data':data,
            'page_menu':page_menu,
            'main_heading':main_heading,
            'title':'iCanteen | Invoice',
            'page_title':'Invoice List',
            'tree_title':'Invoice',
            'search':search,
            'add':add,
            'update':update,
            'view':view,
        }
        return render(request,"base/invoice/table.html",context)
```

**Here attach image I want show the column like this no invoice_no total_tax total_amount **
**Now I don't know calculate total_tax and total_amount **

Comment: what logic do you use to render the table?

Comment: just update in my question

Comment: and how do you render the table (template)?

Comment: data = Invoice.objects.filter(status = 'a')

Comment: how does the `table.html` template looks like...

Comment: invoiceItem_id=InvoiceItem.objects.values("invoices__id","invoices__invoice_no","invoices__create_by","invoices__create_at","invoices__status").annotate(gst_total = Sum((F('quantity')*F('items_price__price')*F('items_price__gst__gst')/100)),total =Sum(F('quantity')*F('items_price__price'))) solve it using this

Comment: now facing the second problem is roundup 2 decimal values

Comment: you can use `Round`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/database-functions/#round